# How to work on offline mode in SUP(sybase unwired platform) for ios application

Tags: ios, sup

I am pure iOS developer I dont know any thing about Sybase Unwired Platform, I have some task related to SUP offline mode, I dont have any idea what I do for offline mode, I already research on http://infocenter.sybase.com but I dont get any help from this link.

Please help me if you know any useful link or any sample source code or anything related to the same share with me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

After 2.1#3, the method `offlineLogin` got deprecated. I am not sure how to get it done now.

Answer (score 0):

SUP APIs works very intelligently. You can login to SCC in offline mode as per [infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com):

**OfflineLogin authenticates against the last successfully authenticated credentials. There is no communication with Unwired Server in this method.**

You have to call below method instead of onlineLogin: or login:

`- (BOOL)offlineLogin:(SUPString)user password:(SUPString)pass;`

While subscribing the package in offline mode, it will return you the previous sync persisted data.

Answer (score 0):

Any SUP App has to be ONLINE on there first run.  This uses the following method
`onlineLogin` method of the DB file. For all other run you can use `offlineLogin` method of the DB file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the offline capabilities like creating local database(sqllite) in device by using phonegap. I have tested it in my hybrid app and it is working fine.